# Compartilhar Variaveis entre arquivos PHP

Tags: php, html

Bom dia, gostaria de compartilhar os dados digitados num input entre 2 arquivos. Na action do Form eu uso o arquivo validação, pra verificar o login e senha, mas queria que os dados digitados nesses campos também fossem para outro arquivo, para eu mostrar o nome do usuario, conforme seu login, pra isso precisaria passar a variável $login para o segundo arquivo:

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
```

nos dois arquivos,  no 1° para verificação e no 2° para consulta no DB. Grato desde já.

Comment: Sessão - http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.session.php ou Cookies - http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php

Comment: no arquivo da action do form coloquei $_SESSION['login'] = $login; e
$_SESSION['cpf'] = $cpf; e fiz com q esse arquivo que recebe essas variaveis por post redirecionasse o navegador para o 2° arquivo em eu preciso dessas variaveis tambem, e pra testar dei um echo $_SESSION['login']; mas isso retorna o erro "Undefined variable: _SESSION "

Comment: Tambem tentei $_SESSION[$cpf] = $_POST['cpf']; e echo $_SESSION[$cpf];

Comment: Utilizando Cookies foi possivel resolver o problema, da seguinte forma:
1° Arquivo: 
setcookie("cpf", $cpf);
setcookie("login", $login);
//
2° arquivo:
$cpf = $_COOKIE["cpf"];
$login = $_COOKIE["login"];

Obrigado, Pedro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em todas as páginas que você precisará declarar / usar uma `SESSION`, você deve iniciar uma sessão no inicio de tal página, para tal você precisa usar o seguinte comando: `session_start()`, uma vez iniciada a sessão, você pode atribuir valores como `$_SESSION["login"] = $login`.

Agora na segunda página basta realizar o procedimento de iniciar a sessão novamente com `session_start()` e depois chamar o valor que você quer `echo $_SESSION["login"]`.

Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre sessões [Aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Já havia conseguido resolver o problema com cookies, mas vou utilizar sessions para evitar o acumulo desnecessário de cookies que podem gerar algum inconveniente. Obrigado!